# Entity Framework Adding ID of one table to another causes optimistic concurrency exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 tables say, Customer and Order. 
When I create a new Order, I have to create a new Customer and put the newly created order ID in the Customer table.
I am using EF4.
In my method I create a new Order, then call _context.SaveChanged(), and get the new order.ID.
In the same method, using the same context, then I create a Customer.
I put
customer.OrderID = order.ID;

Now when I save changes to save the new customer (using _context.SaveChanged()), I get OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

In both Order and Customer I have a DateTime field with ConcurrencyMode=Fixed.

If I only save Order or Customer separately I do not get this exception.

Any suggestions please on what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can't just use the object-graph? `customer.Order = order`?

Comment: Is your Order updated with the new DateTime value after the first save? If not, then if the second save tries to re-save the order, the the concurrency error will occur.